# Should there be an article before "rebound" in "a need for (a) rebound"?

Tags: articles, countability

Consider this sentence:

> He admits that the reason he initially contacted her was a need for a rebound.

Is it better to avoid the second "a" and just leave it "a need for rebound"?

Comment: This concept -- "the need for rebound" with our without "a" is not idiomatic.

Comment: I understand it. It means having a date to help you get over a recent break-up.

Answer (score 1):

Most singular count nouns require a determiner, so the original sentence is correct. Your version (". . . a need for rebound") could work if "rebound" were considered a mass noun. I think that most people would consider that to be pretty unusual, though. ("Rebound" is normally a count noun.)

Answer (score 0):

"... **a rebound**..." is correct.

The full expression is, "a rebound date", which is countable, so the "a" is required.

Comment: Thank you, guys!